# With php-fpm.conf what is the default value for "pm"?

Tags: php-fpm

According to https://www.php.net/manual/en/install.fpm.configuration.php for `pm` there are:

> pm string
>
> Choose how the process manager will control the number of child processes. Possible values: static, ondemand, dynamic. This option is mandatory.
>
> **static** - the number of child processes is fixed (pm.max_children).
>
> **ondemand** - the processes spawn on demand (when requested, as opposed to dynamic, where pm.start_servers are started when the service is started.
>
> **dynamic** - the number of child processes is set dynamically based on the following directives: pm.max_children, pm.start_servers, pm.min_spare_servers, pm.max_spare_servers.

But it does not say what the default value is.

I guess "static" but it would be nice to be certain.

Answer (score 2):

There is no default. This option is mandatory. If this option is missing the error will be returned.

Comment: Thank you very much. I think they should add this to the docs.

Comment: The words "This option is mandatory." are in the documentation you quoted in your question.